# @Entity is not being detected on the entity class

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

So when I try to put the @entity annotation to the student class and also create a student repository, I am getting an error: **Parameter 0 of constructor in com.example.SpringProject.Student.StudentService required a bean of type 'com.example.SpringProject.Student.StudentRepository' that could not be found.**

The project structure is:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2PKLm.png)

Here is my Student Class (entity class)

```
package com.example.SpringProject.Student;


import javax.persistence.*;
import java.time.LocalDate;


@Entity
@Table
public class Student {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(
            name = "student_sequence",
            sequenceName = "student_sequence",
            allocationSize = 1
    )
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
            generator = "student_sequence"
    )
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private LocalDate dob;
    private String email;
    private Integer age;

    public Student() {
    }

    public Student(Long id, String name, LocalDate dob, String email, Integer age) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.dob = dob;
        this.email = email;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public Student(String name, LocalDate dob, String email, Integer age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.dob = dob;
        this.email = email;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public LocalDate getDob() {
        return dob;
    }

    public void setDob(LocalDate dob) {
        this.dob = dob;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public Integer getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(Integer age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", dob=" + dob +
                ", email='" + email + '\'' +
                ", age=" + age +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Here is the student repo:

```
package com.example.SpringProject.Student;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface StudentRepository extends CrudRepository<Student, Long> {
}
```

Here is the student service: (business logic)

```
package com.example.SpringProject.Student;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Month;
import java.util.List;

@Service
public class StudentService {

    private final StudentRepository studentRepository;

    @Autowired
    public StudentService(StudentRepository studentRepository) {
        this.studentRepository = studentRepository;
    }

    public StudentRepository getStudentRepository() {
        return studentRepository;
    }

    public void saveStudents(Student student)
    {
        this.studentRepository.save(student);
    }

    public List<Student> getStudents() {
//        
            return (List<Student>) studentRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

Here is the StudentController:

```
package com.example.SpringProject.Student;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Month;
import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "api/v1/student")
public class StudentController {

    private final StudentService studentService;

    @Autowired
    public StudentController(StudentService studentService) {
        this.studentService = studentService;
    }

    public StudentService getStudentService() {
        return this.studentService;
    }

    @GetMapping
    public List<Student> testStudent()
    {
        this.studentService.saveStudents(new Student(1L,
                        "xyz",
                        LocalDate.of(2001, Month.SEPTEMBER, 22),
                        "xyz@gmail.com",
                        21));
        return this.studentService.getStudents();
    }
}
```

When I tried running the application I got the following error:

```
Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'studentController' defined in file [/Users/nikhil/Desktop/SpringProject/target/classes/com/example/SpringProject/Student/StudentController.class]:
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'studentService' defined in file [/Users/nikhil/Desktop/SpringProject/target/classes/com/example/SpringProject/Student/StudentService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: No qualifying bean of type 'com.example.SpringProject.Student.StudentRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

Comment: Can you share code of class StudentController ?

Comment: Please take care ob java naming conventions. package names should be lower case

Comment: Wild guess. Using Spring Boot 3, following a Spring Boot 2 tutorial and decided to include some additional `persistence-api` dependency because that is what the tutorial uses. Remove that dependency and fix the imports to `jakarta.persistence` instead of `javax.persistence`.

Comment: I am confused. The title talks about an entity not being found, but the body of the question is about a service bean (or rather, a Repository) not being found. Those are two different things.

Comment: Well yes the StudentRepository is not identified by spring as I am trying to autowire the StudentService constructor. The title describes the fact that even after applying @entity annotation to the Student class, it is not being identified as an entity for ORM to be done.

Comment: Hi. Try removing the @Repository annotation. Its not needed for CrudRepository. Let me know what happens after that.

Comment: The error is still the same

Comment: Please, show your pom.xml and SpringProjectApplication class